# Make AsyncTask within RecyclerView on a specific page

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I make an AsyncTask call and create a content slider with RecyclerView.

The slider that is generated is 2 pages or 3 pages.

On the second or third page, I have to make the AsyncTask makelist call.

If I add `new makeList().execute();` inside `onBindViewHolder`, the list is always generated on the first page.

I tried to insert `new makeList().execute();` into other methods like `onItemChanged` using the `position` variable, but without success.

How do I make an AsyncTask call on a specific RecycleView page?

This is part of the code, I think it's the fundamental part:

```java
    @Override
        public void onCurrentItemChanged(@Nullable RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int adapterPosition) {
            onItemChanged(adapterPosition);
        }
    
        private void onItemChanged(int position) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onScroll(float scrollPosition, int currentPosition, int newPosition, @Nullable ListServiceAdapter.ViewHolder currentHolder, @Nullable ListServiceAdapter.ViewHolder newCurrent) {
        }
    
        private class MyService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    
            String content="";
    
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                ListService = null;
                ListService = new ArrayList<ListServiceModel>();
            }
    
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    
               //RETURN content from CALL
    
                return content;
            }
    
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    
                JSONArray jsonArray2 = null;
                JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
                    jsonArray2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("service_1");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
    
                if (jsonArray2.length() != 0) {
    
                    try {
    
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
    
                            JSONObject item_json = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i);
    
                            final ListServiceModel item = new ListServiceModel();
                            item.desc(item_json.getString("desc"));
                            ...
    
                            ListService.add(item);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    
                    mAdapter = new ListServiceAdapter(ListService);
                    scroll_1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    
                }
    
            }
    
        }
    
    
        
        public class ListServiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListServiceAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    
            private List<ListServiceModel> data;
            private View v;
    
            public ListServiceAdapter(List<ListServiceModel> data) {
                this.data = data;
            }
    
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                View v =null;
                
    
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_Service, parent, false);
    
    
                return new ViewHolder(v);
    
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
    
                tempValues = null;
                tempValues = (ListServiceModel) data.get(position);
    
    
                holder.name.setText(tempValues.getName());
    
    
            }
    
    
            private void onItemChanged(int position) {
    
      
            }
    
    
            public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {
    
                ListServiceModel tempValues2 = (ListServiceModel) ListService.get(mPosition);
    
    
            }
    
            private class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
                private int mPosition;
    
                OnItemClickListener(int position) {
                    mPosition = position;
                }
    
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
    
                    onItemClick(mPosition);
                }
            }
    
            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
    
                return data.size();
            }
    
            class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
                private TextView desc;
                ...
    
                @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
                    ....
                }
    
    
            }
    
        }
```

This is the list generated with AsyncTask to be executed within a RecycleView page:

```java
    private class makeList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    
            String content="";
    
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}
    
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    
    
                //RETURN content from CALL
    
    
                urlist = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray jsonArray4 = null;
                JSONObject jsonObject4;
                try {
                    jsonObject4 = new JSONObject(content);
                    jsonArray4 = jsonObject4.getJSONArray("list");
    
    
    
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JSONObject jsonInner;
                String nome;
    
    
                for (int count = 0; count<jsonArray4.length(); count++){
    
                    try {
                        jsonInner = jsonArray4.getJSONObject(count);
                        name = jsonInner.getString("name");
    
                        ServiceListModel obj = new ServiceListModel(nome);
                        urlist.add(obj);
    
    
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    
                }
    
    
                return String.valueOf(urlist);
    
            }
    
    
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                mAdapter_2 = new ServiceListdapter(context, urlist);
                recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter_2);
    
            }
    
        }
```

**EDIT:**
This is where I am trying to insert the makelist execution, but evidently it is wrong

```java
           //This is where the data is written, which will be shown in each generated slider
           @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
    
                tempValues = null;
                tempValues = (ListServiceModel) data.get(position);
    
    
                holder.name.setText(tempValues.getName());

                //On the second page, i would like to generate a list.
                //Done in this way is not correct, the list is generated on the first page. 
                //Even if I do "if position=1" the list is always generated on the first page

                new makeList().execute();
    
    
            }
```

I also tried to insert the function execution here. It seemed to be the solution, but the scroll seems not to be correctly identified, the list sometimes appears on one page other times on another, other times nowhere or is simply generated when I start moving the slider before the scroll is completed indifferently from the page where I am.

```java
@Override
public void onScroll(float scrollPosition, int currentPosition, int newPosition, @Nullable ListServiceAdapter.ViewHolder currentHolder, @Nullable ListServiceAdapter.ViewHolder newCurrent) {
    if(newPosition == 1){
         new makeList().execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not correct way. Inside recycler view there is no possibility to use view model (which support lifecycle). To adapter you should put only simple data to display.

Another think -- AsyncTask was prepared long time ago. If your project allow to use something newer (like ViewModel) use it. With AsyncTask you will probably have memory leaks when you close view before onPostExecute(...).

When you get the responses from async you can update recyclerView adapter using notifyDataChanged(...)

Comment: Thanks for the information about AsyncTask and ViewModel, surely I am committed to change it everywhere in the app.

In the meantime, is there no way to solve my problem? I guess that's not possible with ViewModel either.

I need to generate a dynamic list on a specific page within the RecycleView.

It surprises me that there is no solution

Comment: I do not know if I understand correctly -- you want to make sliding pages and in this pages are recyclerview processed from single page? If yes, you can use ViewPager and put fragments inside -- then it will be easy to call async job from each fragment (it will have also lifecycle support)

Comment: Can you give me an example or link something? I create a slider with RecycleView. In an X page of this slider i have to make another call. Normally the dynamic content on each page is managed by holder. But how do I execute a new call on a specific page?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide

Comment: Thank you @M. Liver , I managed to implement ViewPager which generates N pages based on the size of the list. I can't understand how to pass dynamic data from the AsyncTask call to the various pages

Comment: Do you want to run AsyncTask in each fragment in view model or in level at view pager? If you want to run in each fragment I can't see problem -- just normal call async task. When you want to get data from second way (call on viewpager level) I can't see easy way to do it -- this effect you can achieve by using view model shared (only one instance injected in all fragments/activities) and using liveData.

Comment: The first call AsyncTask creates N dynamic fragments, I have to pass the data into these fragments, and I'm having some trouble passing the data into each fragment, all the fragments show the data that should only be present in the last one. The second AsyncTask call must be made and print data only in the second fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The result of first asyncTask probably returns the list with fragment datas. You should create each fragment in view pager using this list. It is simple for me -- if you stil have problem please show me code snippet.

Comment: This is the activity: https://paste.notify.me/ewecedorit.http
This is the fragment: https://paste.notify.me/enedibaret.java
All information taken in the call from the activity must be displayed dynamically in each fragment. Subsequently in specific fragments another call must be made (but we will see this later)

Comment: Show me adapter too

Comment: adapter is on the activity page; "ScreenSlidePagerAdapter"